# @Hidden annotation to hide a controller

Tags: swagger-ui

I am trying to use @Hidden annotation for hiding a whole controller. when I put it in top of one of the api's it hide it from the swagger fine but when I put in top of the whole class it does nothing and not hiding all the api's. what I am doing wrong?
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq3pt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this annotation to hide a controller:

```
@Schema(hidden = true)
```